# Data Masking on DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am keen to learn if anyone knows if DynamoDB supports Data Masking out of the box? Can't seem to find it in the documentation; understand that there are third parties that offer that capability.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hush-Hush](https://mask-me.net/Products.aspx) Sensitive Data Discovery Tool and Data masking components effectively mask data in the backend. The masking process is an ETL process implemented by using SQL server and SSIS packages.

Answer (score 0):

As of today (March/1/2021), Amazon DynamoDB supports encryption at rest and in transit but does not support data masking out of the box. There are solutions such as [FINRA Maskopy](https://finraos.github.io/maskopy/), or the [Serverless Tokenization solution](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-a-serverless-tokenization-solution-to-mask-sensitive-data/), and many other 3rd party that supply customers with solutions that will run in the backend and mask the data.